# Converting a digit from char to integer in C language

Tags: c, type-conversion, char, digits

I'm reading the C programming textbook<sup>1</sup> and in 1.6 they're saying the conversion between a char containing a digit and an int can be done like this:

```
char character = '7';
int integerChar = character - '0';
```

I'm having trouble understanding what is happening here and why the integer value is equal to the character minus the character `'0'`.

---

<sup>1</sup>
Brian W Kernighan and Dennis M Ritchie
[The C Programming Language, 2nd Edn](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131103628) 1988.

Comment: You might want to do a web search on "ASCII table"...

Comment: The character values of `'0'` through `'9'` are consecutive.  So `'1'` is `'0' + 1, etc.  Subtracting `'0'` gives the displacement from the character `'0'`, which is the integer represented by the character.  `'0' - '0'` is obviously zero, `'1' - '0'` is `('0' + 1) - '0'`, which is one, etc.

Comment: Also, when not packed into an array, one normally uses an `int` to hold a character value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the C Standard (5.2.1 Character sets)

> 3. ...In both the source and execution basic character sets, **the value of
>    each character after 0 in the above list of decimal digits shall be
>    one greater than the value of the previous**.

So it means that the Standard guarantees that for example the difference `'1' - '0'` is equal to `1`, or the difference  `'2' - '0'` is equal to `2` and so on.

So independent of the internal representation of characters as for example ASCII or EBCDIC you can get an integer digit that is represented by a character `c` like `c - '0'`.

For example in the ASCII character table the characters `'0'` through `'9'` have codes from `48` up to `57`. In the EBCDIC character table they have codes from `240` up to `249`.

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    for (char c = '0'; c <= '9'; c++)
    {
        printf( "'%c': %d\n", c, c - '0' );
    }
}
```

The program output is

```
'0': 0
'1': 1
'2': 2
'3': 3
'4': 4
'5': 5
'6': 6
'7': 7
'8': 8
'9': 9
```

Comment: If you still don't get it, `printf( "'%c': %d - %d = %d\n", c, c, '0', c - '0' );`

Answer (score 3):

In the symbol table (such as classic ASCII), C guarantees that the symbol values from `'0'` to `'9'` are placed in a contiguous sequence. In practice it might look like:

```
48  '0'
49  '1'
50  '2'
...
```

So when you subtract `'7'` - `'0'` it is the very same thing as `55 - 48 = 7`. Only now you have a real integer value and not a symbol table value.

To illustrate with an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
  char a = '0';
  char b = '7';
  printf("'%c' is %d\n", a, a);
  printf("'%c' is %d\n", b, b);
  printf("%d - %d = %d\n", b, a, b-a);
}
```

Output:

```
'0' is 48
'7' is 55
55 - 48 = 7
```

Comment: Is "symbol table" a good choice of words here?  It has a specific meaning for compilers, and might be a little misleading.  Would "code set" be a better choice?

Comment: Or character set. "Symbol table" also irked me

Comment: @JonathanLeffler And I can't say ASCII or UTF8 or some EBCDIC fan will complain about that instead...

Comment: Yeah — it's fiddly.  But even in EBCDIC, the digits are consecutive code points (240-249 IIRC).  I suppose that these days, using "one of the ISO 8859 code sets or UTF-8" covers many cases, and a "such as" qualifier always works to cover a multitude of not dreadfully important details.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do `- '0'` operation *if and only if* you need to use the `char` as an `int`
Example:

```
 char c = '7';
 int a = c;
```

If you print the integer with its integel value,

```
 printf("%d", a);
```

you'd get `55`. That is because the value in the memory of the `int` contains `'7'` in the memory, and it's int value will be `55` in ASCII table.

If you print the integer using char, it takes the char value and gives you `7`

```
 printf("%c", a);
```

Note that, while printing the formats must be fitting, for example you can't print float value `%f` on an int, because float on print expects `double`, due to more memory being required. (Double is 8 bytes, hence int and char are 4 byte values)

The result of operation `char - char` will be integer in the case of the char's being numericals. So in range of `0` to `9`.

So if you were to print

```
printf("%d", '9' - '2');
```

This will give you `7` as an an integer and not char because the result of that equation result into an `int`.

So, substracting basic `'0'` char from a char is an easy way to get an integer value in return, leaving the char being substracted in its original form.